# Clonezilla suggests using -C parameter but then rejects it as unknown

Tags: partitioning, clonezilla

I would like to use Clonezilla to backup one partition to another on my Ubuntu 20.04 computer. The source partition is 1000GB and is about 40% full. The target partition is 991GB and is empty. Both source and target are formatted as ext4.

When I try running Clonezilla, it reports the size difference and says, "Use Option -C to disable size checking". And if I try running it again using that parameter, it says that -C is not a valid parameter.

Otherwise, the parameters are:
-e1 auto -e2 -r -j2 -sfsck -k -pa choose -f sda2 -t sdb2

So, can I use clonezilla in this case or is it an absolute requirements that the target partitions be >= the source partition?

Comment: I use Clonezilla a lot and have always stuck to the requirement that the target partitions be >= the source partition. But you can create an **image** (which is compressed and occupies approximately half or less of the partition size (depending on how much free space there is).

Comment: An alternative is to work on the file level and use `sudo -Havn source/ target`, and after the dry run remove the option `n` to do the real thing.

Comment: @sudodus I am not sure what you mean by
        `sudo -Havn source/ target`

Comment: Sorry, stupid me. I forgot the tool itself: It should be `sudo rsync -Havn source/ target` -- 'source' and 'target' are the mountpoints for the source partition and target partition.